# Correct JMS ConnectionFactory to use for transactional read

Tags: transactions, jboss, jms

What would be the correct JMS connectionFactory to use if one wants a transactional read ?

I want that in a sucessful transaction the JMS message will be read from the message queue and in a failure senario(exception) the message will be available in the queue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the failure scenario you mention is with respect to your application and not the messaging provider. If there is some exception in your application, then you would like the message not be removed from the queue and the same can be received later.

If that is the case, use a Queue Connection factory and then create a transacted session. If the message is processed successfully by your application then issue session.commit() else do a session.rollback().